# Firebase cloud messaging every guest with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have subscription Firebase Cloud Messaging and setup on flutter (iOS and Android) is working, but I have a question.

This function sends the message to all of it who have install my app.

How is the function that every guest have his own subscription, if a day the subscription is expired, send a message "Hello, you subscription is expired!".

How should you specify or how does the logic function so that the message only reaches users whose subscriptions are about to expire?

Answer (score 1):

You can store (or erase it) local notification with date, without firebase.
Alternative on backend, or cloud function then send a push. But honestly i think local is better for simple cases

Comment: Oh...how? more people say me that it is advisable to use FIREBASE CLOUD MESSAGING or ONESIGNAL, are perfect but is working that every 30 minutes send message on push notification to all of it who have install my app. But I can't find a way to send push notifications to whoever I want to send... for example, 10 iPhones have my app installed, each iPhone has its own account (ID and USER CODE), if I wanted to send a push notification to a specific user code or id, how do you do it?

Comment: You can use topics of channels for this cases